# how to pass form data between WordPress forms contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, forms, contact-form

I have two forms in my word press site, foam A and form B.
I want to pass form A name field value into form b name field after click submit button form A. I have used many plugins for this.can I do this using php function or WordPress plugin.hope your help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is hook documentation that might help you:

https://xaviesteve.com/3298/wordpress-contact-form-7-hook-unofficial-developer-documentation-and-examples/

You ll need to add new function to your functions.php file to create custom forms.

In form B for value name you can pass variable

```
$firstname = $WPCF7_ContactForm->posted_data['firstname'];
```

Hope it helps.